# Como escrever um número por extenso em Linguagem C?

Tags: c

estou fazendo um programa aqui de um trabalho da faculdade, e não sei como dar valor a uma string, o meu programa vai mostrar o numero que eu digitar por extenso. E eu nao estou conseguindo dar o valor pra variavel de acordo com string.

Vou inserir o código para vocês olharem.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define N 3

// ESTOU PENSANDO EM DIVIDIR O NUMERO EM 3 PARTES NE AI DA PRA EU PEGAR O PRIMEIRO VALOR QUE E O MAIS SIGNIFICATIVO E VER EM QUAL CENTENA ELE ESTA

int main(){

    char nume[N];
    char centenar[20];
    char centena[9]={'cento','duzentos','trezentos','quatrocentos','quinhetos','seiscentos','setecentos','oitocentos','novecentos'};
    int i=0;
    int num,resultado,cent;

    printf("Digite um numero para ser escrito por extenso:");
    scanf("%d",&num);

    resultado = num / 100;

    printf("%d",resultado);

    cent = resultado;

    switch(cent){
        case 0: centenar = centena[0];break;
        case 1: centenar = centena[1];break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Você tentou ao menos compilar o programa ?

Comment: @user49003 você deveria ter se esforçado um pouco mais e tentado compilar. Você não chegou a atribuir nenhuma string. Você também cometeu o erro de atribuir uma variável para um array de char. Vou tentar bolar uma resposta legal ao invés de simplesmente dar uma solução, OK? Mas tente pesquisar um pouco sobre o tema e ir tentando bolar sua própria solução! É importante para seu aprendizado e também para sua carreira! :)

Comment: Se eu utilizar o número 13. Como o "U" no final da conta u = n - (n / 10) * 10 é = a 3?

Comment: @AlessandraJulia acredito que você queria perguntar na resposta do @Lacobus. Mas explico: quando você divide um _número inteiro_ (tipo `int`) por outro inteiro, ele não fornece decimal pois _não é um número real_ (tipo `float`). No caso, 13/10 é igual a 1, com resto 3 (resto ignorado). E 1*10 é igual a 10. Portanto, 13-10 é igual a 3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Vejamos...

A *sua dúvida* é pertinente a não conseguir atribuir um valor à uma **variável do tipo "string"** - que na verdade, ***não existe em C*** como um tipo. Mas **existe *vetor de `char`*** (caracteres), que acaba sendo a **mesma coisa** só que não abstraído o suficiente pra gerar um tipo novo. Mas, para melhorar a legibilidade do texto, vou chamar esse "vetor de `char`" de *string*.

*- Assim sendo, como fazer uma string em C?*

---

## Explicando um *vetor de char* (string)

É, na verdade, bem simples:

```
char minha_string[12] = "Ola, Mundo!\0";
printf("%s", minha_string);
```

O resultado em tela, no seu terminal ou prompt de comando, será, por conta do `printf()`:

```
Ola, Mundo!
```

O que foi feito é **muito simples**: cria-se um *vetor de `char`* e define o tamanho dele baseado na quantidade de caracteres de sua suposta "string" - incluindo espaços e símbolos - mais um. Esse "+1" existe pois é necessário informar o ponto de término da "string" ao utilizar o carácter `\0`, que o C encara como um *delimitador de "strings"*.

**Note que** `\0` é um único caractere e tem seu próprio código *ASCII*, *UTF-8* ou qualquer que seja a tabela de caracteres utilizada. Só que, por ele não ter uma representação própria, utilizamos o conjunto `\` e `0` para representá-lo. Se quiser, visite o artigo sobre a [Tabela ASCII](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) na Wikipédia e e veja as representações de escape existentes. Pode procurar mais informações sobre o assunto também.

*Assim*, uma simples "string" como `Ola, Mundo!` tem 11 caracteres. Ao somar +1 por conta do *delimitador de "strings"*, ficamos com 12 ao todo. Definimos então o tamanho do vetor de `char`, nossa "string",  para 12.

Você pode ainda acessar cada caractere desse vetor individualmente. Lembre-se que se o tamanho é 12, o acesso se dá de 0 à 11. Assim:

```
printf("%c", minha_string[1]);
```

Resulta em:

```
l
```

**MAS** é importante notar que, se você tem um texto grande ou não quer contar, poderia simplesmente fazer:

```
char minha_string[] = "Ola, Mundo!\0";
```

O resultado será o mesmo! O compilador faz essa contagem para você e determina o tamanho do vetor ***antes*** de, de fato, compilar o código.

Com isso, já é o suficiente para sanar a dúvida que consta em sua pergunta. Mas, você com certeza vai perguntar o que se segue pois é uma dúvida 'embutida':

*- E se eu quiser fazer um vetor de "strings", como é que fica?*

## Explicando um *vetor de "strings"*

Na verdade, *um vetor de "strings" é também uma matriz de `char` e vice-versa*, dada agumas resalvas. Explico mais adiante. Só observe que isso é válido para C. Em qualquer outra linguagem em que `string` exista como seu próprio tipo independente de `char`, um vetor de `string` **pode não ser** uma matriz de `char`.

***Matriz é a uma estrutura de dados do tipo vetor com duas ou mais dimensões***. A matriz de duas dimensões, chamada de *matriz quadrada*, é que vai importar neste momento: cada linha existente dela possui N colunas.

Se lembrar da matemática, o entendimento é facilitado. Este artigo sobre [Matriz](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matriz_(matem%C3%A1tica)) da Wikipédia pode vir a ajudar a entender um pouco do conceito geral de matriz na computação.

Curiosidade: para gráficos em 3 dimensões (3D), usamos matrizes cúbicas! Independente disso...

Enquanto que um vetor é geralmente declarado e atribuído da seguinte forma:

```
int meu_vetor_de_inteiros[3] = { 50, 60, 70 };
```

Uma matriz *quadrada* seria definida da seguinte forma:

```
int matriz_de_int[3][4] = {
    50, 60, 70, 0,
    80, 90, 40, 1,
    30, 20, 10, 2
}; /* Poderia ter sido tudo em uma linha mas atrapalharia a percepção */
```

O primeiro `[3]` indica a primeira dimensão da matriz. A segunda dimensão é indicada por `[4]`. Não vem ao caso mas geralmente a primeira dimensão é chamada de linha e a segunda de coluna- não vai ser um conceito útil se entendermos como "string"; mas se entendermos como `char`, `int` e outros tipos será bastante útil).

Na prática, a diferença de uma matriz de inteiros para um vetor de inteiros - e vice-versa - é apenas como se declara e interpreta esse vetor. Não muda a forma como se define ele via código.

Se considerarmos a `matriz_de_int`, se poderia obter um resultado equivalente ao definir o seguinte vetor de `int`:

```
int vetor_int[3*4] = { 50, 60, 70, 0, 80, 90, 40, 1, 30, 20, 10, 2 };
```

Um vetor de "strings" (e também uma matriz de `char`) se configura da seguinte forma:

```
char vetor_de_string[3][12] = {
    "abcdef",
    "Saudacoes!",
    "xyz"
}; /* O uso de aspas duplas permite caracteres de escape como \0 ou \n */
```

Podemos acessá-lo da seguinte forma:

```
printf("%s\n%c", vetor_de_string[0], vetor_de_string[2][0]);
```

Resulta em:

```
abcdef
x
```

Por este motivo, um vetor de "string" é, de certa forma, uma matriz de `char`: podemos tanto usar o `printf()` com `"%s"` para obter uma linha inteira como "string" ou usar `"%c"` para obter uma coluna de uma linha, que é um `char` (um único caractere).

Entretanto, se definirmos a seguinte matriz de char que equivale a um vetor de `char`:

```
char matriz_de_char[3][12] = {
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f',
    'S', 'a', 'u', 'd', 'a', 'c', 'o', 'e', 's', '!',
    'x', 'y', 'z'
}; /* não há delimitador de string; é então, na prática, um vetor */
```

Não teríamos o mesmo resultado. Seria equivalente a ter feito um vetor de `char` conforme segue:

```
char vetor_char[3*12] = { 'a', 'b', ..., 'z' }; /* Igual a matriz_de_char */
```

Assim, ao acessar `vetor_char` e `matriz_de_char` da mesma forma como fizemos para o caso do vetor de "strings":

```
printf("matriz: %s\n%c\n", matriz_de_char[0], matriz_de_char[2][0]);
printf("vetor: %s\n%c", vetor_char[0], vetor_char[2][0]);
```

Teríamos:

```
matriz: abcdefSaudacoes!xyz
o
vetor: abcdefSaudacoes!xyz
o
```

Antes de mais nada, saiba que os espaços não utilizados, em se tratando de `char`, são preenchidos automaticamente com `\0`. Ou seja, como foram definidos 12 colunas do tipo `char` para cada uma das três linhas, ao todo 36 espaços, todos os espaços excedentes recebem `\0`. Esses `\0` (nulo) não serão impressos; serão ignorados. E o comportamento difere de caso para caso:

- no caso de um vetor de "strings", são contabilizados os espaços excedentes de cada linha individualmente por conta das aspas duplas. No exemplo dado anteriormente, na linha 0, teríamos na prática o valor `"abcdef\0\0\0\0\0\0"` - o que contabiliza 12 espaços da linha.
- no caso de uma matriz de `char` em forma de vetor `char`, os espaços são também contabilizados. Mas, como ininterruptamente foram preenchidos os espaços, somente depois de `"xyz"` que os espaços serão na verdade preenchidos com `\0`, ficando `"...xyz\0\0\0...` até completar os 36 espaços.

Também é importante saber que programa então converte este `[2][0]` da seguinte forma: `[2]*12 + [0]*3 - 1` -> `[23]`. Ou seja, na verdade, utiliza-se o `[23]`. Este "-1" existe pois o acesos a vetores começa em 0 e vão até o tamanho máximo menos um.

Dito tudo isso, **o que acontece é o seguinte**: no caso do vetor de "string", ao final de cada string (todo o *conteúdo entre aspas dupla*) há o preenchimento com um ou mais do caractere `\0` - ele é, afinal, nosso delimitador de "strings". Já no caso da matriz de `char`, não existe tal delimitador separando as strings repartidas em caracteres e é utilizado aspas simples. Logo, se considerarmos como "string", ele joga na saída todo o texto a partir do ponto especificado com `[valor]` (conforme a regra de conversão de `[]` e `[][]` explicado no parágrafo anterior). Exemplo:

```
printf("%s\n%c\n", matriz_de_char[1], matriz_de_char[1][0]);
```

Teríamos:

```
oes!xyz
o
```

Dessa forma, se tivéssemos feito a matriz de `char` conforme exemplo que se segue abaixo, o resultado seria mais satisfatório mas longe de ser igual, na maioria dos casos, a um vetor de "string". Veja:

```
char nova_matriz_de_char[3][12] = {
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', '\0',
    'S', 'a', 'u', 'd', 'a', 'c', 'o', 'e', 's', '!', '\0',
    'x', 'y', 'z'
};

printf("%s\n%c", nova_matriz_de_char[0], nova_matriz_de_char[2][0]);
```

Resulta em:

```
abcdef
```

***Em ambos os casos***, tanto para um vetor de "strings" quanto para uma matriz de `char` que não se comporte como um vetor de `char`, se for feito o acesso a um caractere individualmente, devem-se ter cautela. Na prática, para o camputador, em cambos os casos, o que temos é que se segue:

```
/* Para o `vetor_de_string` */
"abcdef\0\0\0\0\0\0",
"Saudacoes!\0\0",
"xyz\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"

/* Para a `matriz_de_char` */
"abcdefSaudac"
"oes!xyz\0\0\0\0\0"
"\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"

/* Para a `nova_matriz_de_char` */
"abcdef\0Sauda"
"coes!\0xyz\0\0\0"
"\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
```

Fica fácil notar que o acesso aos caracteres pode não ser bem o pretendido e pode ser que se tenha acessado um caractere `\0` (nulo). Nada acontecerá conforme exemplo dado com `nova_matriz_de_char`.

Desta forma, se quiser realmente a abstração de "strings", adote o sistema de `vetor_de_string`. Use um vetor ou matriz de caracteres somente para o caso de não haver tratamento de "strings".

*NOTA*: alternativamente, para diminuir ainda mais o trabalho, **poderia ter sido** ignorada declaração de tamanho das dimensões subsequentes à primeira. Ficaria então assim:

```
char minha_matriz_de_char[3][] = {
    "abcdef",
    "Saudacoes!",
    "xyz"
};
```

## Analisando o erro

Vamos então analisar o código que você providenciou. O amigo, ao tentar criar um *vetor* de *strings*, fez o que se segue:

```
char centena[9] = {'cento','duzentos','trezentos','quatrocentos','quinhetos','seiscentos','setecentos','oitocentos','novecentos'};
```

*- "Mas o que foi que eu fiz de errado?!"*

Acredito que você mesmo já deva ter percebido o erro: você criou, na verdade, um vetor de caracteres (`char`) e atribuiu um vetor de "strings" a ele. Você queria é um vetor de "strings" (que é um uma matriz de `char` com uso de *aspas duplas*).

Agora pode prosseguir em desenvolver sua lógica! :)

## Conclusão

As aspas fazem a diferença assim como a forma de agrupar os caracteres. Se quiser uma "string", utilize aspas duplas ao invés de aspas simples e não separe os caracteres individualmente - a menos que queira trabalho extra para configurar cada `\0` no local apropriado. E não se deve confundir um vetor com uma matriz.

Como de praxe, coloco minha versão desse programa. Recomendo que olhe somente depois de fazer o seu. Está no [GitHub](https://github.com/jfcandidofilho/stackoverflow/blob/master/num2txt/num2txt.c).

Answer (score 4):

Segue um exemplo de código (testado) capaz de exibir o número por extenso em português.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


static const char * unidades[]  = { "Zero", "Um", "Dois", "Tres", "Quatro", "Cinco", "Seis", "Sete", "Oito", "Nove" };
static const char * dez_vinte[] = { "", "Onze", "Doze", "Treze", "Quatorze", "Quinze", "Dezesseis", "Dezessete", "Dezoito", "Dezenove" };
static const char * dezenas[]   = { "", "Dez", "Vinte", "Trinta", "Quarenta", "Cinquenta", "Sessenta", "Setenta", "Oitenta", "Noventa" };
static const char * centenas[]  = { "", "Cento", "Duzentos", "Trezentos", "Quatrocentos", "Quinhentos", "Seiscentos", "Setecentos", "Oitocentos", "Novecentos" };


char * strcatb( char * dst, const char * src )
{
    size_t len = strlen(src);
    memmove( dst + len, dst, strlen(dst) + 1 );
    memcpy( dst, src, len );
    return dst;
}


char * traduzir_numero( char * nome, int n )
{
    int c = n / 100;
    int d = n / 10 - c * 10;
    int u = n - (n / 10) * 10;
    int dv = d * 10 + u;


    strcpy( nome, unidades[ u ] );

    if( n < 10 )
        return nome;

    if ( (dv > 10) && (dv < 20) )
    {
        strcpy( nome, dez_vinte[ dv - 10 ] );
    }
    else
    {
        if( u == 0 )
        {
            strcpy( nome, dezenas[ d ] );
        }
        else
        {
            strcatb( nome, " e " );
            strcatb( nome, dezenas[d] );
        }
    }

    if( n < 100 )
        return nome;

    if( (d == 0) && ( u == 0 ) )
    {
        if( c == 1 )
            strcpy( nome, "Cem" );
        else
            strcpy( nome, centenas[c] );
    }
    else
    {
        strcatb( nome, " e " );
        strcatb( nome, centenas[c] );
    }

    return nome;
}


int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    int i = 0;
    char extenso[ 100 ] = {0};
    int num[] = { 0, 1, 10, 13, 100, 123, 321, 111, 333, 777, 910, -1 };

    while( num[i] != -1 )
    {
        traduzir_numero( extenso, num[i] );

        printf( "%d: %s\n", num[i], extenso );

        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}

/* fim-de-arquivo */
```

Saída:

```
0: Zero
1: Um
10: Dez
13: Treze
100: Cem
123: Cento e Vinte e Tres
321: Trezentos e Vinte e Um
111: Cento e Onze
333: Trezentos e Trinta e Tres
777: Setecentos e Setenta e Sete
910: Novecentos e Dez
```

Espero ter Ajudado!