# Ajuda em um exercício em c

Tags: c

Boa noite.

Estou com duvida de como e por onde começar o seguinte algoritmo:

Escrever um algoritmo que em c que receba um numero de um cheque e escreva a palavra equivalente. Por exemplo, o valor 112.43 deve ser escrito como
CENTO E DOZE e 43/100

Por favor, não me digam a resposta, mas me de um caminho de onde posso começar.

Comment: Faça tratamento especial para os valores de 1 a 19. Divida o número em algarismos de acordo com a posição e aplique o extenso de cada algarismo. Uma boa solução é tabela de unidades, de dezenas e de centenas, além do 1 a 19.

Comment: Obrigado, agora já sei por onde começar.

Comment: Caso esteja com dúvidas, [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/152233/122392) satisfaz sua pergunta. Sei que não queria a resposta mas sim uma ajuda, bom, essa resposta é muito bem detalhada e garanto que será de boa ajuda. :)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como escrever um número por extenso em Linguagem C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/152029/como-escrever-um-n%c3%bamero-por-extenso-em-linguagem-c)