# Escrever numero por extenso de 0 até 10000 em linguagem c++

Tags: c

Preciso de ajudar para escrever números por extenso de 0 até 10000. Eu só consegui escrever até 1500, como pode observar abaixo:

#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

```
float a; 
printf ("Digite um numero de 1 a 1500:\n");
scanf ("%f", &a); 
                             
if (a>1500) 
   printf ("O numero deve ser menor do que 1500\n");

else 
     {             
     if (a>=1000)
        {
        printf ("mil ");            
        a=a-1000;      
        }                         
         
     if (a>=100)            
        if (a>=900)
           {                       
           printf ("novecentos ");               
           a=a-900;               
           }
                 
        else if (a>=800)               
           {
           printf ("oitocentos ");               
           a=a-800;               
           }   
           
        else if (a>=700)               
           {               
           printf ("setecentos ");               
           a=a-700;               
           }
           
        else if (a>=600)               
           {               
           printf ("seiscentos ");                
           a=a-600;              
           }
                                
        else if (a>=500)
           {               
           printf ("quinhentos ");                 
           a=a-500;               
           }
           
        else if (a>=400)
           {               
           printf ("quatrocentos ");               
           a=a-400;               
           }   
           
        else if (a>=300)
           {               
           printf ("trezentos ");               
           a=a-300;               
           }
           
        else if (a>=200)
           {               
           printf ("duzentos ");               
           a=a-200;               
           }
                                                       
        else if (a>=100)
           {               
           printf ("cem ");               
           a=a-100;               
           }      
     
      if (a>=10)
        
        if (a>=90)
           {                       
           printf ("noventa ");               
           a=a-90;               
           }
                 
        else if (a>=80)               
           {      
           printf ("oitenta ");               
           a=a-80;               
           }   
           
        else if (a>=70)               
           {               
           printf ("setenta ");               
           a=a-70;                        
           }
           
        else if (a>=60)               
           {               
           printf ("sessenta ");                
           a=a-60;              
           }
                                
        else if (a>=50)
           {               
           printf ("cinquenta ");                
           a=a-50;               
           }
           
        else if (a>=40)
           {               
           printf ("quarenta ");               
           a=a-40;
           }   
           
        else if (a>=30)
           {               
           printf ("trinta ");               
           a=a-30;               
           }
           
        else if (a>=20)
           {               
           printf ("vinte ");               
           a=a-20;               
           }
                                                       
        else if (a>=10)
           {               
           printf ("dez ");               
           a=a-10;               
           }                   
           
      if (a>=1)
        
        if (a>=9)
           {                       
           printf ("nove ");               
           a=a-9;               
           }
                 
        else if (a>=8)               
           {      
           printf ("oito ");               
           a=a-8;               
           }   
           
        else if (a>=7)               
           {               
           printf ("sete ");               
           a=a-7;                        
           }
           
        else if (a>=6)               
           {               
           printf ("seis ");                
           a=a-6;              
           }
                                
        else if (a>=5)
           {               
           printf ("cinco ");                
           a=a-5;               
           }
           
        else if (a>=4)
           {               
           printf ("quatro ");               
           a=a-4;
           }   
           
        else if (a>=3)
           {               
           printf ("tres ");               
           a=a-3;               
           }
           
        else if (a>=2)
           {               
           printf ("dois ");               
           a=a-2;               
           }
                                                       
        else if (a>=1)
           {               
           printf ("um ");               
           a=a-1;               
           }     
        
       if (a>0,00)
                                   
          if (a>=0,90)
             {                       
             printf ("noventa ");               
             a=a-0,90;               
             }
          
          else if (a>=0,80)
             {                       
             printf ("oitenta ");               
             a=a-0,80;               
             }
          
          else if (a>=0,70)
             {                       
             printf ("setenta ");               
             a=a-0,70;               
             }
             
          else if (a>=0,60)
             {                       
             printf ("sessenta ");               
             a=a-0,60;               
             }
          
          else if (a>=0,50)
             {                       
             printf ("cinquenta ");               
             a=a-0,50;               
             }
          
          else if (a>=0,40)
             {                       
             printf ("quarenta ");               
             a=a-0,40;               
             }
          
          else if (a>=0,30)
             {                       
             printf ("trinta ");               
             a=a-0,30;               
             }
          
          else if (a>=0,20)
             {                       
             printf ("vinte ");               
             a=a-0,20;               
             }
          
          else if (a>=0,10)
             {                       
             printf ("dez ");               
             a=a-0,10;               
             }
                      
           
           
        }
     
fflush (stdin);
getchar ();
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em português. O que você já tentou? Assim quem for responder vai poder ver sua dúvida e conseguir te ajudar. Se puder editar sua pergunta para incluir sua tentativa seria muito legal.

Comment: Encontrei algo em [tag:C] aqui no [pt.so] veja [Como escrever um número por extenso em Linguagem C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/152029/como-escrever-um-n%C3%BAmero-por-extenso-em-linguagem-c)

Answer (score 0):

Você está usando a técnica errada para criar números por extenso.

Você deve primeiro fazer um mapeamento das partes que compõe um número genérico na base 10 para o texto por extenso. Isso é feito de forma estática (vetores).

Só então você pega o número e o quebra em suas partes constitutivas, no caso na base 10.

Por exemplo:

6523 = 6000 + 500 + 20 + 3 = 6 (milhares) + 5 (centenas) + 20 (dezenas) + 3 unidades.

O mapeamento é trivial:

```
char unidades_str[] = {zero, um, dois, três, quatro, cinco, seis, sete, oito, nove};
char dezenas_str[] = {dez, vinte, trinta, quarenta, cinquenta, sessenta, setenta, oitenta, noventa};
//etc.
```

Agora, pegue um número, por exemplo: 23 (entrada) -> vinte e três (saída)

O teu programa faz assim:

```
23 % 10 = 3 -> resto 3 (unidades)
23 / 10 = 2
2 % 10 = 2 -> resto 2 (dezenas)
2 / 10 = 0 -> pare!
```

Veja outro número: 431

```
431 % 10 = 1 -> resto 1 (unidades)
430 / 10 = 43
43  % 10 = 3 -> resto 3 (dezenas)
43 / 10 = 4
4 % 10 = 4 -> resto 4 (centenas) 
4 / 10 = 0 -> pare!
```

Em C:

```
int numero = get_number();  //tem que ser feita essa função
int itens = 0;

unidades = numero % 10;
itens++;
numero = numero / 10;
if(numero == 0) goto fim;
dezenas = numero % 10;
itens++;
numero = numero / 10;
if(numero == 0) goto fim;
centenas = numero % 10;
itens++;
numero = numero / 10;
if(numero == 0) goto fim;
//etc.
fim:
   switch(itens) {
       case 0: printf("Não é um número válido\n"); break;
       case 1: printf("%s\n", unidades_str[unidades]); break;
       case 2: printf("%s e %s\n", 
                          dezenas_str[dezenas],
                          unidades_str[unidades]); break;
       case 3: printf("%s e %s e %s\n",
                          centenas_str[centenas], 
                          dezenas_str[dezenas],
                          unidades_str[unidades]); break;
       //etc.
   }
```

Claro que aqui só tem as ideias principais, mas acho que é suficiente para você terminar a sua lição!